# Never ending Loading... message when a Angular2 CLI project is deployed to Github using gh-pages

Tags: angular, web-deployment, github-pages, angular-cli

Good day everyone!

I deployed a freshly created Angular2 CLI Project to GitHub pages.

`Problem is - the "Loading.." message` which appears on the start of any angular 2 app `never ends..`

I checked the network calls - as you can see below - all the files are downloaded correctly.

I'd say is a GitHub server problem because **on Local-host everything works**, and exactly the same files are downloaded. Except the "live" ones. (which are `ember-cli-live-reload.js`, `livereload.js?snipver=1`, `livereload`)

**Screen shot:** 
[image]

**QUESTION: Why the app works on localhost but not on github? How could i solve this? Thank's so much!**

**Edit:** 
I was wrong, somehow is not a Github problem.. could be a Mozilla problem..

I checked the app on ***Chrome browser - works just fine!! On Local-host and on the GitHub servers***

The odd thing is that:

***Local-host server and Mozilla browser - works***.

***Github server and Mozilla browser - doesn't*** - how to solve this?

I have Mozilla Firefox 48.0.2.

Comment: I have the same version of FF and it works for me. But only if i closed console:)

Comment: Yeah man, that's right! It works now- with the console closed - you rely should post this as an answer. Crazy little bugs :) Thank's!